# Обязательно ли использовать все три голоса на выборах?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

На выборах модератора у голосующего есть три голоса, которые он может отдать за кандидатов на финальном этапе выборов. Будет ли "бюллетень" избирателя считаться действительным, если отдать только один или два голоса кандидатам?

Comment: Вам настолько не нравятся оставшиеся семь кандидатов? Представьте, что один из ваших фаворитов выбыл. Кто из оставшихся станет модератором?  Выберите меньшее из зол. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin в ситуации когда вы **ничего** не знаете ни про одного кандидата - правильной стратегией будет не идти на выборы, передав тем самым право выбора тем, кто заведомо знает не меньше вас.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr: Можно использовать не все голоса, бюллетень будет действительным и будет работать так же, как полный.**

---

Как утверждает Википедия касательно [методики выборов STV, используемой у нас](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0):

> Правила конкретных выборов могут устанавливать ограничения на минимальное или максимальное число кандидатов, которых может ранжировать избиратель — например, бюллетень может считаться действительным, только если в нем ранжированы все кандидаты. Кроме того, правила могут позволять или не позволять избирателю указывать для нескольких кандидатов одинаковый уровень предпочтения.

То есть, *гипотетически* это очень даже возможно. Методика позволяет свободно смешивать в одних выборах бюллетени с разным числом предпочтений.

Для алгоритма указание менее 3 кандидатов означает лишь то, что перенос голоса в случае победы или выбывания выбранного кандидата будет возможен меньше двух раз, а потому больше шансов, что ваш голос уйдёт в "exhausted" (выбывшие).

---

#### Но перейдём к фактам.

Гляньте на [бюллетени с выборов на Stack Overflow этого года](https://www.opavote.com/ballots/5927932925050880/0?p=4). Список начинается с бюллетеней, имеющих голос всего за одного кандидата.

[При этом результаты выборов гласят](https://www.opavote.com/results/5927932925050880):

> The number of voters is 30582 and there were 30582 valid votes and 0 empty votes.

> Число избирателей 30582, действительных голосов 30582, пустых голосов 0.

Они внесены в систему и действительны, а значит участвуют в подсчёте.

Чисто технически, можно убрать голоса за всех кандидатов вообще. Для алгоритма не будет разницы, ушёл ли ваш голос сразу в exhausted или его не было вовсе, ни на какие показатели в процессе подсчёта (порог победы, веса кандидатов) он не повлияет. Посему, он не будет засчитан "против всех".

Comment: А почему количество голосов равно количеству участников, если каждый может по три голоса отдать?

Comment: @alexolut нет, голос один. Преференций три. Он размажется между ними.

Comment: странно, при голосовании сказано именно "1й голос", "2й голос" и т.д. Оригинал не смотрел пока, но может стоить поправить формулировку тогда?

Comment: @alexolut уточню: можно считать, что голосов три, но но результаты влияние окажет только один, в зависимости от того, кто победит (и с каким перевесом) или отвалится. Текущая формулировка мне, как пользователю, понятна. Когда я её увидел впервые (на выборах en.SO) я ещё не знал про STV и вот это всё :)

Comment: @D-side Учитывая используемую методику переброса голосов (Meek), работать могут и два голоса, результирующие значения могут быть дробными (в сумме всё равно один голос).

Comment: @Squidward я именно об этом. Что в сумме по весам от каждого возьмётся только один голос, но он может размазаться по нескольким кандидатам.

Answer (score 2):

Технически, алгоритм устроен таким образом, что длина списка предпочтений может быть любой. Движок SO ограничивает его сверху - но не снизу.

*Более того, если аккуратно подойти к выбору структур данных - можно даже обеспечить возможность два раза голосовать за одного и того же кандидата; но это бессмысленно потому что подобный второй голос лишь уменьшает "вес" избирателя не влияя на этого кандидата*